# 貢がせる verb and its usage

Tags: grammar, translation

> **遠坂にそんな高価な品を貢がせる悪しき男**はあたしが天に代わって誅罰を下してくれるわー！キエー！」

【貢がせる女、貢ぐ男】
 1. 思わせぶりな態度で男に貢がせようとする女のこと。
 2. セックスのために売春婦に金を払う男、または付き合うために女に貢ぐ男。

The evil man who is tricking Tohsaka with precious goods.
Is this correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it's the other way around. The sentence says "the evil man who makes Tohsaka present expensive things to him." It's Tohsaka who is buying goods.

貢ぐ is a transitive verb which means *to present/offer* (to a king/emperor/etc, as a tribute). As a slang term, it's commonly used in the form of `person + に貢ぐ`, and means to keep supplying gifts/money/etc (to attract attention of someone whom they like).